# Can Tkinter ask for input from a different page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a gui with tkinter where I am being redirected to different pages and I want those different pages to ask for different inputs and do different functions. As of now I still can't fix it I am just using this tkinter as of today so I am new.
what I envision is:
Page 1: ask student section
Page 2: ask for something else
Page 3: ask for something else again
although it seems to display it for all the pages.

I tried changing the values of the win in the tk.label to the page value to maybe display it on the page itself although it will result in a blank so I reverted it.
This is the output if I go to other pages.
[page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6hfQ.png)
[page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imQiF.png)
for page 3 it is the same as the first two.
This is the code that I have used.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font
import os
import cv2
win = tk.Tk()
style1 = font.Font(size=25)


page1 = Frame(win)
page2 = Frame(win)
page3 = Frame(win)

page1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky="nsew")
page2.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky="nsew")
page3.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky="nsew")

lbl1 =Label(page1, text = " This is Page 1", font=style1)
lbl1.pack(pady=20)

lbl2 =Label(page2, text = "This is Page 2", font=style1)
lbl2.pack(pady=30)

lbl3 =Label(page3, text = " This is Page 3", font=style1)
lbl3.pack(pady=50)

lbl1p2 = tk.Label(win, text="Enter Section", width=20 , height=2 , fg="black" , bg="white", font=('times', 15, ' bold ') ) 
lbl1p2.place(x=300, y=200)
txt1 = tk.Entry(win, width=20, bg="white", fg="black", font=('times', 15, ' bold '))
txt1.place(x=550, y=215)

btn1 = Button(page1, text = "Show page 2", command = lambda: page2.tkraise(), font = style1)
btn1.pack()
btn1p2 = Button(page1, text = "Show page 3", command = lambda: page3.tkraise(), font = style1)
btn1p2.pack()
message1 = tk.Label(win, text="", bg="white", fg="black", width=30, height=2, font=('times', 15, ' bold ')) 
message1.place(x=550, y=400)
btn2 = Button(page2, text = "Show page 1", command = lambda: page1.tkraise(), font = style1)
btn3 = Button(page2, text = "Show page 3", command = lambda: page3.tkraise(), font = style1)
btn2.pack()
btn3.pack()
btn4 = Button(page3, text="Show page 1", command= lambda: page1.tkraise(),font=style1)
btn5 = Button(page3, text="Show page 2", command= lambda: page2.tkraise(),font=style1)
btn4.pack()
btn5.pack()

def getfolder():
    while True:
        dataset_folder = input("Please input the section of the students: ")
        if not os.path.exists(dataset_folder):
            print("Datasets folder does not exist")
        else:
            print("Folder found...")
        break

page1.tkraise()
win.geometry("1200x600")
win.title("Main menu")
win.resizable(False, False)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you mean by "page"? Tkinter GUIs do not have those.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should seperate your pages. Like these situations, using OOP would be life saver. Creating instance or class per page will solve problems.

first of all lets create a base page class that will have everything we need.

```
class Page:
    def __init__(self,frame,pageName):
        self.pageName = pageName
        self.frame = frame

    def _LoadPage(self):
        #clear inside frame
        for child in self.frame.winfo_children():
            child.destroy()
```

This way, we will get container frame and we will empty it before fill everytime new page opened.

this is an example student page class

```
class StudentPage(Page):
    def __init__(self,frame,pageName,studentName):
        super().__init__(frame,pageName)
        self.__studentValues = {"Student Name":studentName}
    def loadPage(self):
        #do studentPage placement.
        self._LoadPage()
        row = 0
        for i,j in self.__studentValues.items():
            tk.Label(self.frame,text=f"{i}: {j}").grid(row=row,column=0)
            row += 1
```

as you can see here you can have information of student in a dictionary like studentvalues.

```
class OtherPage(Page):
    def __init__(self,frame,pageName):
        Page.__init__(self,frame,pageName)
        self.pressTimes = 1

    def loadPage(self):
        #do other Page things.
        super()._LoadPage()
        self.label = tk.Button(self.frame,text=f"Button pressed {self.pressTimes} times")
        self.label.grid(row=0,column=0)

        self.__button = tk.Button(self.frame,command=self.doButtonThings,text="Press button to increase")
        self.__button.grid(row=1,column=0)


    def doButtonThings(self):
        self.pressTimes += 1
        self.label["text"] = f"Button pressed {self.pressTimes} times"
```

This is an example for other pages. It keeps how many times you have pressed buttons. Even though you have changed pages it keeps in its memory.

finally create mainwindow, instances etc.

```
win = tk.Tk()
style1 = font.Font(size=25)

#left part would be like a menu
buttonsFrame = tk.Frame(win)
buttonsFrame.place(relx=0,rely=0,relheight=1,relwidth=0.3)

#right side will be a place where content will be shown
layoutFrame = tk.Frame(win)
layoutFrame.place(relx=0.3,rely=0,relheight=1,relwidth=0.7)

#create pages
sp = StudentPage(layoutFrame,"Student Page","Nasur")
op = OtherPage(layoutFrame, "a page")

studentButton = tk.Button(buttonsFrame,text="Load student Page",command=sp.loadPage)
studentButton.grid(row=0,column=0)

otherButton = tk.Button(buttonsFrame,text="Load other Page",command=op.loadPage)
otherButton.grid(row=1,column=0)

win.geometry("1200x600")
win.title("Main menu")
win.resizable(False, False)
win.mainloop()
```

Everytime you change a page, base class load page method called and frame cleared.
Your load page method will fill the page as you desired. Also as it's a class pages can their own methods and variables, arrays, dictionaries.